Southern contraction for "let him", spelling
*I know there is no grammatically correct contraction for "let him", I'm looking for an informed guess on how "let him", contracted in a deep southern dialect might be spelled?

You might want to make precise whether you are talking bout AmE or British English. Southern British English is certainly a dialect: Collins Dictionary. "Deep" refers possibly to the  Deep South in the US, but that is not all that evident. "Deep" refers possibly to the  Deep South in the US, but that is not all that evident. The  tags do not refer to an American dialect.

What does this spoken form actually  SOUND like, the first syllable of lemming or similar?

@LPH The tag is correct. Imagine that it represents some white-person version of black AAVE similarly from somewhere south of the Mason-Dixon line. It is not meant to suggest SSBE.

BTW, gender-neutral, Mason-Dixon line to Gulf states: Let 'em eat pound cake. Let'um eat poke cake. (It ain't Latin, buddy, but somebody's gonna get hit.)

@HippoSawrUs Oh THAT one! That gets used everywhere there are native speakers. It's certainly grammatical. The question is how one should write the weak form so it's clear to the reader that the front part of him/them is unheard.

JSYK, we all talk like that in the South, all the time except in church, to the law, or on job interviews. This is not AAE, which mainly differs with be verbs, possessive forms, and -n't contractions such as haven't and doesn't (not big fans), But we all slur words together or change verb tenses for emphasis: Uuh, I betty don't! (Huh, I bet he doesn't!). They're not really contractions, per se.

@tchrist - Really, you would say 'Let'um eat poke cake' to mean 'Poke his eye out'? LOL. Good to know. I'll be more nicer from now on...

It’s not a contraction; it’s an omission: Let ’im. As in Let ’er rip.

To my ears, there would be no difference between 'led'm' meaning 'let them' or 'let him' Am I mishearing this?
